# Disable Clear Case asking to add new sources

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I'm using Clear Case with Eclipse and having a problem with Clear Case asking me to add specific files to source control, whenever I compile a programm or exit eclipse. The thing is that these files should not be put under version control.

Is this something that can be disabled and when yes, where?

It can also be, that I configured something wrong, as this is a problem which I didn't find a quick solution for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your exact client, or ClearCase plugin inside your Eclipse, but from "[Configuring Eclipse workspace preferences](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_eclipseprefs.htm)" (Here using the ClearTeam Explorer, based on Eclipse), you should have an option similar to:

```
Automatically add to source control
```

> if you want the Rational ClearTeam Explorer to add each new resource to source control automatically.

If you don't use the CLearTeam GUI, but the SCM Adapter, see "[ClearCase SCM Adapter preferences](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_9.1.0/com.rational.clearcase.help/doc/CCPrefs.htm)".
"[**When new resources are added**](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_9.1.0/com.rational.clearcase.help/doc/PrNewRes.htm)":

> - If you want to be prompted to add any new resources to source control, select `Prompt to add to source control`.
> - If you want to add any new resources to source control, select `Automatically add to source control`.
> - If you do not want either option, select `Do nothing`.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I'm using the SCM Adapter and have found the entrys I was looking for.